# How to drop multiple columns in Pandas with different labels and same row values

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

How can I drop multiple columns in a Pandas DataFrame if they have different labels but same row values?

```
  A B C D E
0 1 1 1 2 2
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 1 1 1
3 0 1 0 0 0
```

I want a df with only A,B,D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way `duplicated`

```
df=df.loc[:,~df.T.duplicated()]
df
   A  B  D
0  1  1  2
1  0  0  0
2  1  1  1
3  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I have found so far to drop multiple columns with same values and different labels. It works by converting each columns values to a list then converting that to a string, then using drop_duplicates().

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,1,0,],'B':[1,0,1,1],'C':[1,0,1,0],
        'D':[2,0,1,0],'E':[2,0,1,0]})

# Create a separate data frame
dff = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['labels','lists'])

for col in df.columns.values:

    # Convert each column to a list
    dff.loc[len(dff)] = [col, df[col].to_list()]

# Convert list to string
dff.lists = dff.lists.astype(str)
dff = dff.drop_duplicates('lists')
new_cols = dff.labels.values
df = df[new_cols]

  A B D
0 1 1 2
1 0 0 0 
2 1 1 1
3 0 1 0
```